# django datetime.datetime error

Tags: python, django, datetime

While following the tutorial [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/), I get down to where you run `poll.was_published_today` and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/myDir/mySite/polls/models.py", line 11, in was_published_today
    return (self.pub_date() == datetime.date.today())
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable
```

Here is the code for my poll class:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

    def was_published_today(self):
        return (self.pub_date() == datetime.date.today())
```

I've tried a few different things and it always chokes on any mention of "datetime".

This code:

```
import datetime
datetime.date.today()
```

when run in the interpreter works fine, just as expected, but in my file, it doesn't.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you calling your field like a function?

Comment: @Ingacio: Doh!  This is why I come here.  So I don't spend even *more* hours working on a bug the first other set of eyes sees.  While I did mess that up, it didn't fix it.  It still produces the same traceback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typo. Should be

```
def was_published_today(self):
    return (self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today())
```

Comment: Yes I had messed that up, but that didn't fix it.  It still produces the same traceback.

Comment: I don't understand. When I did the tutorial, I had the exact same code. I just tested it again and it still works. I guess, what Python version and what Django version are you using?

Comment: @Robert: Python 2.6.5 and Django 1.2.3.

Comment: @John - I'm stumped. I'm running those versions, with the same code (literally! I did the same tutorial last month), and have no problem.

Comment: @Robert: I just got it working.  Really strange, it was(IS!) treating `import datetime` the same as `from datetime import *`.

Comment: You're still the accepted answer though because you *did* fix *one* of my problems, just not the one I asked the question about! :D  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it.  For some reason it's treating `import datetime` like `from datetime import *` (Anyone know why?)  So removing `datetime` from

`return (self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today())`

corrected it.  I also decided to import datetime *first* though I don't know if that did anything.

The working file(for me) is:

```
import datetime
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

        def was_published_today(self):
            return self.pub_date.date() == date.today()
```

Comment: I'm absolutely flabbergasted. I've *NEVER* seen Python do that. There's a reason the `from` syntax is so different - it's to avoid namespace pollution. You probably still have a problem, but I'm glad you've gotten it working.

Comment: @Robert: My thoughts *exactly*.  Do you think I can ask a question why it's doing this or will it get closed as a dupe of this?

Comment: Eh... well it effectively *is* a dupe, now that we've figured out what it was... but you're well off the 'newest' list by now. Make sure to reference this question so you're upfront about it

Comment: @Robert: I asked it.  Do you think I was clear enough?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468256/import-module-from-module-import