# import module == from module import *?

Tags: python, django, django-models, module, import

[I had a problem with the Django tutorial so I asked a question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466164/django-datetime-datetime-error/4468112#4468112)  No-one knew the answer, but I eventually figured it out with help from [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52721/robert).  Python seems to be treating `import datetime` the same as `from datetime import *`.

Working code:

```
import datetime
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

    def was_published_today(self):
        return self.pub_date.date() == date.today()
```

Not working code: (The only differences are the import statements and the last line.)

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

    def was_published_today(self):
        return (self.pub_date() == datetime.date.today())
```

**EDIT:** I guess I wasn't clear enough.  The code produces the *exact same traceback with the last line being* `return (self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today())`  Me originally forgetting to add `.date()` is **NOT** the error I'm asking about.

The traceback produced by the not working code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/myDir/mySite/polls/models.py", line 11, in was_published_today
    return (self.pub_date() == datetime.date.today())
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable
```

Why on earth is it doing this?

My question is **NOT** about forgetting `.date()`.  My question is: Why is datetime in my namespace without me using `from datetime import *`.

*Note: The first question asked **what** it was doing.  This question asks **why.***

**UPDATE:** Suddenly it works.  With `datetime.date.today()` **AND** `date.today()`.  My question remains though, why does `date.today()` work?  It seems datetime is in my local namespace without me putting there.  Why?

Comment: Your Python installation must be seriously messed up.

Comment: Shouldn't `self.pub_date()` in the second case be `self.pub_date.date()`, just like in the first case?

Comment: That's really odd. Works normally when I just do `import datetime; datetime.date.today()` with none of the Django stuff.

Comment: I guess self.pub_date is not callable.

Comment: @Alok: That's one reason that's the code that **doesn't** work.

Comment: @Rafe: Yes, me too.  In a different file in the same folder it works fine, just not it this file.

Comment: @John but does the second script run if you use `self.pub_date.date()`?

Comment: @Rafe: No it does **NOT**.  It produces the exact same traceback.

Comment: By __exact__ you mean even the "return (self.pub_date() == datetime.date.today())" part?

Comment: @Kabie: After I add `.date()` it still produces the same traceback.

Comment: what's the output of `print datetime` from within the file.

Comment: Maybe the view file import this model happened contains `from datetime import *`? And if you use `self.pub_date.date()`, the traceback should show `self.pub_date.date()` instead of `self.pub_date()`.

Comment: @dan: I added it right before the return and nothing different happened.

Comment: @John, it didn't print anything? try putting it at the beginning of the file after the import.

Comment: @Kabie: I see your point now.  The *error* is the same.  The *traceback* differs in that `.date()` is added.

Comment: @Dan: Still nothing....I'm so confused.

Comment: @John, try changing it to `assert 0, repr(datetime)`

Comment: @John: Then it shouldn't raise `TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable` after using `self.pub_date.date()`.

Comment: I've had some weird issues like this too with Django + datetime. Hopefully this gets resolved.

Comment: @Kabie: I know it *shouldn't* but it *is*.

Comment: @Dan: If I put it right after the imports it should execute when that file itself is imported right?  It doesn't seem to be.  Changing `print datetime` to `assert0, repr(datetime)` do not change anything that I saw.  Importing my polls file still didn't print anything.

Comment: I was able to get the code running. It's not your full environment, obviously, but the code imports and runs. I do not get the same effect you did.

Comment: @Lennart: -bangs head on desk-  Yes, Robert said he did the exactly same tutorial last month without problem.

Comment: @John: Well, start with understandning what pdb is and how to use it. Then learn how to interpret a traceback. Then I'm sure you'll find the problem.

Comment: @Lennart: I know how to interpret a traceback(I think anyway).  It makes no mention of my file *at all*!  What I don't get is why polls is not defined when `import polls.models` works fine.

Comment: Oh, you are talking about the traceback when you tried to use pdb. Sigh.

Comment: @John, If nothing is happening I don't think it is being run. Are you sure you are making changes to the right file? if you put `print models` or whatever you've imported it as in your view file then does it show the correct file name?

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to print that. I don't think it's updating properly before you are re-running the code. Try removing the assert and print statement and retrying ayaz's answer.

Comment: @dan: Just retried that.  I've no idea why but suddenly I'm getting the debug prompt that Lennart said I should but I never did.  Also, `date.today()` correctly, no longer works.  What do you think isn't updating?  Put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Are you using Django's auto-reloading server?

Comment: @dan: I was only aware of one Django server:the development one.  It's not running now.  I'm not sure if it was running the first time I tried these suggestions, but I'm trying to find out.

Comment: @john, I mean, are you checking the answers using Django's server or the shell or what?

Comment: @dan:I have been and am checking the answers in the shell.

Comment: do you reload the shell for each change?

Comment: @Dan: No.  I'm starting the get the feeling that was a *big* mistake....

Comment: @Dan: -facepalm- Well now I feel stupid.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @john, you learnt something, it wasn't a complete loss.

Comment: @Dan: Yes, I'm also very glad that there are people like you who stick with me until it's fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, the problem is not with the code, but the way you are updating the source. python caches modules in `sys.modules`. You can reload individual modules using the `reload` function, but for many changes it's best to reload the entire shell. In many cases it looked as though the changes had propagated because the error messages seemed to have changed, this is because python doesn't cache the source code of the file, so when it references code, it shows you the newest version. Hopefully now, you can apply the other answers with more success.

Answer (score 4):

The problem in the latter snippet is with this part of your code:

```
return (self.pub_date() == datetime.date.today())
```

`self.pub_date` contains a `datetime.datetime` instance. It's not callable like that. For example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> d()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable
>>>
```

If you want to compare only the `date`, you should call it thus:

```
return (self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today())
```

Comment: Take a look at the other question. He got an error on that, but if you remove `datetime` from the second half of the `==` he's OK. The question isn't the `pub_date.date()` (although he has a typo in the question) but why `datetime` seems to be poisoning his namespace without using a `from`.

Comment: I already tried that.  I covered that in the answer to the other question. `return (self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today())` **does not work!**

Answer (score 2):

"My question is: Why is datetime in my namespace without me using from datetime import *."

Because you did import datetime. Then you have datetime in your namespace. Not the CLASS datetime, but the MODULE.

Python does *not* treat `import datetime` the same way as `from datetime import *`. Stop asking why it does that, when it does not.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date.today()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'date' is not defined
>>>
```

There is something else happening. If it's Django magic or not, I don't know. I don't have a Django installation where I can try this at the moment. (If there is a super-quick way of making that happen, tell me. easy_installing Django wasn't enough. :) )

Comment: I know Python *shouldn't* treat them the same but I looks to me like it *is*.  I also think something else is happening, but what?

Comment: @John: That's probably trivially easy to figure out by sticking a pdb in the code. But I can't do that, as I don't know how to make the code example actually runnable, since I haven't used Django for two years. :-) I'm **guessing** Django magically craps all over your locals() but that's just a wild guess.

Comment: @Lennart: The output of that is here: http://pastebin.com/2eRuxajV  Unfortunately, I don't understand what that output means.  I'm not sure I did that right, that was my first time ever using pdb.

Comment: I should probably add that `import polls.models` works fine in the interpreter.

Comment: @John: Just before the line where the error happens, stick `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()`. Then you'll be able to inspect local variables and step into the methods, etc.

Comment: @Lennart: I don't think my file is causing that error.  The traceback has no mention of my files.  Nevertheless, I added that at the very beginning of the file.  There was no difference.  It produced the same traceback as I put in pastebin.

Comment: OK, once again: **Just before the line where the error happens, stick import pdb;pdb.set_trace()**. Not at the beginning of the module, but **ON THE LINE BEFORE THE ERROR HAPPENS**. You will get a prompt. There you can debug.

Comment: @Lennart: The pdb traceback.  The one I put in pastebin and linked to a few comments ago.  *That* traceback makes no mention of my file.

Comment: @Lennart: The presence of `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` did not appear to change anything.  From the interpreter I again tried `pdb.run('polls.models')` and received the `polls is not defined` traceback.

Comment: I never said the presence would change anything. I said: **You will get a prompt. There you can debug.** Please read what I say, this is turning out to be  a big waste of time otherwise. Did you not get a debug prompt? I have no clue why you are trying to do `pdb.run('polls.models')` from the interpreter.

Comment: @Lennart: It's presence not changing anything means that when I run the file I get no prompt.

Comment: Well, that's also impossible. Things are clearly not as you say they are. That line *will* start a debug prompt, so you can not get an error on the line after without getting a prompt.  I suggest you delete everything and restart.

Comment: @Lennart: Yes you are probably right.  At least, I hope it's something that simple!  Thanks for your help.