# Why is it bad practice to use from module import *?

Tags: python, module

As a 'habit', almost everyone in stackoverflow and example pages use `import numpy as np` 
and then type

```
t = numpy.arange(0,40000,4000)
```

Why don't we/Why is it bad practice to use `from numpy import *`
and then type

```
t = arange(0,40000,4000)
```

Please give me reasons. 
(My guess: 
1. In case we need to import more than one module, some functions in different modules share the same name. 
2. At [import module == from module import *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468256/import-module-from-module-import), I can see that this 'habit' results in faster processing time.) What are some other reasons?

Comment: Definitive reference: http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says about it:

> Wildcard imports ( `from <module> import *` ) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools. There is one defensible use case for a wildcard import, which is to republish an internal interface as part of a public API (for example, overwriting a pure Python implementation of an interface with the definitions from an optional accelerator module and exactly which definitions will be overwritten isn't known in advance).